# File being used by another process even if closed it before

Tags: c#, .net, exception, filesystemwatcher

I don't understand why the same code runs successfully on a 32-bit system, but trying to run it on a 64-bit system, always gives an error:

> File being used by another process

I declare a file watcher event to watching a file changed.

My code is similar to below:

```
static void Main()
{
   //init load file
   LoadAssembly(dll);

   //bind watching event.
   FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(rootPath, "*.dll");
   watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
   watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(TemplateFile_Changed);
   watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
   watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private LoadAssembly(assemblyFile)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(assemblyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            //read a file and write to memorystream.
            ......
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        asm = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Close();
    }
}

private void TemplateFile_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_sync)
    {              
         LoadAssembly(e.FullPath);           
    }            
}
```

I test code that can work in 32-bit system(in my computer). When I deployed to 64-bit system, when I change a file and tell application need to re-load this file ,that always get a

> File being used by another process`

at

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(assemblyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

updated-1

Well,thanks @Hans Passant answered,this exception it's looks caused by the file watcher  that fired a changed event and still keep file open. I add a Thread.Sleep() in my TemplateFile_Changed looks solved this problem.

```
private void TemplateFile_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_sync)
    {      
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
         LoadAssembly(e.FullPath);           
    }            
}
```

Comment: what is `ms` variable?

Comment: This exception is entirely normal.  When the Changed event fires, the program that's changing the file still has the file opened.  It is *busy* making changes, it isn't done with it.  You'll have to wait.  How long that takes is unpredictable, it depends on how long that other program keeps the file opened.

Comment: Is it possible this other system has anti-virus software that will automatically scan changed files? They are notorious for causing these kinds of issues.

Comment: ms is a memorystream,it just keep a file stream in memory.64-bit system not install a anti-virus software.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `using` you don't need to close `Stream` because it automatically close the `Stream` after `using`; so try this code:

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(assemblyFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        //read a file and write to memorystream.
    }
```

Comment: It's true that you don't need to explicitly Close & Dispose fs with using. But it doesn't matter in this case, this is just unnecessary, but working code. After FileStream.Close() the Dispose() method will just do nothing.

Comment: Neither Close nor Dispose is needed, and I think it should give you a compiler error or a warning on Dispose!

Answer (score 0):

You need to process this exception, this is absolutely normal situation for your application. Imagine that some application takes exclusive rights for file and modifies it - you will get the same exception. But you can do nothing with it - just wait when the application will release the file.

In exception handler you might put such unsuccessfully loaded assemblies to some collection and try to process it later (by timer for example).

Also it might be better architecture for your application to not load assemblies exactly on file change. Put it in queue, group changes and load it periodically. You will avoid unnecessary loads (in case of multiple changes) and split loading logic from file system event handling.